# counting number of checkboxes check in email

Tags: php, html, forms, email

Here is my php code:

```
$tasks = ' ';
$help = $_POST['help'];
if(empty($help))
{
    $tasks = "None selected.";
}
else
{
    $N = count($help);
    $tasks = $N;
}
```

And the HTML is:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="help" value="sign"> //with several inputs with different values
```

On the form submit, it emails and outputs everything appropriately except the count of the array. It outputs the $tasks variable at the end of the email always as 1, except when no check boxes are selected. Any combination of selecting checkboxes (1-6) ends up with an array of 1 length. Anyone know why? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to make the checkboxes an array. Change the name to:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="help[]" value="sign">
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change your HTML code to:

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="help[]" value="sign">
```

so that help will be an array. If you only use `help`, `$_POST['help']` will only contain the last value.

Answer (score 0):

you have to rename fields `name="help[]"` so it can be parsed as array.